# Restarting VM stops network on another VM

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, virtual-machines

So I have a Print server and a Terminal server running as VM's on a Host.  Earlier today, another VM on this host, a Domain Controller that is basically just a file server dropped from the network.  I restarted the DC and found the Print server was not accessible.  Only fix was to restart that server, after which, I found that the Terminal server was no longer showing on the network.  Restarting the Terminal server makes the Print server drop from the network.

The Print server and the Terminal server are accessible from the Windows Server 2012-r2 VM manager and seem to be running fine but are not accessible to any other computers.

They don't seem to be running together but they have been 'forever'.  Trying not to restart the VM manager if possible.  Any thoughts?

**Update:** Shutting both of these down then bringing them up together kicked the File server from the network.  The VM that goes down shows no problems on the VM host but is not pingable or remoteable.

**Update 9/22:** It's Hyper-V Manager, 6 total Virtual Machines, let me know what other info would be helpful.  It looks like there was MAC duplication happening, does this make sense?

**Update 9/23:**  Restarting the Hyper-V Manager machine solved the issue, I'm wondering if I could have spoofed the MAC at least until off-hours?  All I have now relating to the issue is a MAC conflict warning Event ID 16945.

**Update 10/7:** We use an IT company as backup for issues we can't handle, they don't seem to think it was a MAC conflict, they dedicated the network adapters to the host and virtual machines to get that error to stop happening.  Are they wrong?  Hopefully this doesn't happen again but I won't have any new details until it does...

Comment: Could this be something simple like an IP clash?

Comment: @TimFletcher I did check that, they are still set to their different static IP's.

Comment: Tell us about the hypervisor.

Comment: It sounds like MAC collision to me. Do ipconfig /all on both VMs and compare the MAC addresses.

Comment: @DylanKnoll We ended up restarted the Hyper-V manager machine to solve the problem so all I have is an Event log of the MAC conflict.  I can understand why the 2 would be conflicting but don't understand why it kicked a third VM when both were brought down and back up at the same time.  Nothing had changed on the network in a month.  It was definitely a MAC conflict but now I'm hoping to find out why.

Comment: There should be a way in Hyper-V to configure it to give each VM a unique MAC.  Cloning the host's mac sounds like trouble to me.